# typedef stuct initialization in C, referencing it

Tags: c, structure

I have made a typedef struct variable as follows:

```
typedef struct
{
   int x;
   int *someobj;
} test;
```

I saw that sometimes people use the `.` when referencing the object or the `->`, which one is correct to use? Is `->` used only when you initialized a variable of type test?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, (*p).x is equal to p->x. Assuming p is pointer to struct and x is a field inside the struct

Answer (score 2):

You use `.` when the LHS<sup>*</sup> of the expression is a structure; you use `->` when the LHS is a pointer to a structure.  Thus, given:

```
typedef struct Object { int type; void *data; } Object;

Object  o;
Object *p = &o;
```

You normally write:

```
o.type  = 0;
p->data = 0;
```

The `->` notation is a shorthand; you could also write:

```
(*p).data = 0;
```

However, that gets messy with nested structures.  Granted, the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) suggests you shouldn't use either of these, but the notation using `->` below is a lot easier to read than the notation using parentheses, stars and dots:

```
lhs->data->array[10]->name = 0;
(*(*(*lhs).data).array[10]).name = 0;
```

---

<sup>* LHS = left-hand side</sup>

Answer (score 1):

To keep things simple,in the case of structures you use the `.` operator to reference the elements of the structure when you are using a structure variable to do that.But if you are using a pointer to a structure variable to reference the elements, you use the `->` operator.Now let me explain this taking your structure as the example.I am making a slight variation though:

```
typedef struct
{
   int x;
   int *someobj;
} test;

test struct_var,*struct_ptr;
```

The last statement above does two things.First , it declares a variable `struct_var` of the structure type you have mentioned.Second, it declares a pointer to such a structure variable `struct_ptr`;

Now in the following statement we assign the address of the variable to the pointer:

```
 struct_ptr=&struct_var;
```

Now to reference the elements of the structure, we can do that two ways as below:

```
 struct_var.x and  struct_var.someobj    //while using `.` operator
```

and

```
 struct_ptr->x and struct_ptr->someobj      //while using `->` opertor
```

and finally, to dereference the integer pointed by the pointer element `someobj`, use:

```
 *(struct_var.someobj)   or  *(struct_ptr->someobj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You use -> if a variable is pointer, like this:

```
test * myTest = (test*) malloc(sizeof(test));
printf("%d", myTest->x);
```

Otherwise you use . :

```
test myTest;
printf("%d", myTest.x);
```

Comment: The question is tagged `c`, not `c++`.